# How to run Express app with React in production mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have this web app that has this file structure.

[image: een here]

how can I run my web app that has the Production Build of React?
This code in my index.js doesn't work.

```
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

should I execute the command `serve -s build`? in the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `index.js` with this.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
```

and then command `node index.js`